# Flutter won't compile on ios nor android. Empty project wont compile

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Soo... everything worked fine then after taking a break from work apps wont run.
New or empty project it does not matter.
Flutter doctor says everything is fine.

Here is Debug console.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            3.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/bm/_wgnp7b94l78gc2g88cq3kbc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.MW6UxN/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirktvpW1/temporary_xcresult_bundle
/Applications/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:186:7: Error: 'ethrow' isn't a type.
          ethrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
          ^^^^^^
/Applications/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:186:14: Error: Expected ';' after this.
          ethrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Applications/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:186:26: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.
    Try inserting an identifier before '.'.
          ethrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
                             ^
/Applications/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:195:6: Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
        }());
         ^
    Failed to package /Users/stankoo003/minimal_design.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/bm/_wgnp7b94l78gc2g88cq3kbc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.MW6UxN/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirktvpW1/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited
```

```
flutter doctor, empty projects..
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows a problem in Flutter's TickerProvider class.
It might be a version problem. Try `flutter upgrade`.
Clean your project `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` and try building again.

Comment: Sadly, still not working...

Comment: Thank you, it fixed it but only after restarting everything

Comment: @Stankoo003 Happy to hear that. You can now accept my answer ✔